# Gamma-Vega Neutral Portfolio Not Possible with Only 3 Options

Tags: hedging, gamma, vega

Let's say we have sold a call option, x, on a share and we have 2 other call options, y & z, with different strikes and maturities to try and achieve a portfolio that is both Gamma and Vega neutral. We just need to solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
V_x \\ 
\Gamma_x \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
V_y & V_z  \\
\Gamma_y & \Gamma_z 
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
z  
\end{bmatrix} $$

However, a solution only exists if the 2x2 matrix above is invertible, i.e. $V_y \Gamma_z-V_z\Gamma_y\ne0$.

Is there any reason why the solution wouldn't exist or a name given to the situation when it happens? Or does this happen just by chance, that the determinant is 0?

Comment: @noob2 Isn't $ \mathbb{P}\left[\omega \in \Omega \mid V_y \Gamma_z-V_z\Gamma_y = 0 \right] = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Black-Scholes world, we have:

$$V_y= \sigma_y \tau_y S^2 \Gamma_y $$

and similarly for $z$.

Comment: Thanks! So the only way we could have the determinant being non-zero is if the time until expiration is different for both call options.

Comment: Yes, assuming flat implied vol (same for all strikes and times to expiriez), then selected times to expiries must be different.